# HMR with Parcel.js within dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I have a simple Parcel.js 2.0 set up with a main.js file as the starting point:

```
import('./components/faqs/faqs.js').then(function(Faqs){

  Faqs.init()  

})
```

When running parcel watch - I have found that changes to the main.js file HMR as expected, but changes to the linked faqs.js within the init function do not, and require a page refresh.

If I take a synchronous approach such as:

```
import init from'./components/faqs/faqs.js'

init()
```

Then HMR works as intended, refreshing with any changes to the faqs.js. Is this an expected behaviour of Parcel's HMR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged this, and here's a quick description of what currently happens in Parcel HMR with this example:

1. You load `main.js` the first time, and it dynamically imports and loads `faqs.js`.
2. You make a change to `faqs.js`, parcel sends a websocket message to the browser, informing it that the bundle beginning with `faqs.js` needs to be re-loaded. The updated bundle code is downloaded and executed, including a new definition for the `init()` function. Any global side-effects in `faqs.js` will also be re-run. So far, so good.
3. However, probably what you're expecting is that the `.then` callback from `main.js` that actually *runs* the `init` function also re-runs. This doesn't happen because parcel treats the different dynamic bundles independently.

IMO, this seems like a bit of a rough edge of the current implementation of HMR in Parcel2 - I'll file a bug with what I've found so that we can think about possibly improving this.

In the meantime, however, you can work around the problem yourself by providing a callback to `module.hot.accept`, which will be injected by parcel in development mode (see [documentation](https://parceljs.org/features/development#hot-reloading)). For example, you could add this to `faqs.js`:

```js
// "module.hot" is injected by parcel in development mode.
// This check will ensure that this code _only_ runs in this context
// (e.g. it won't affect production)
if (module.hot) {
   // The callback provided to "module.hot.accept" will be run whenever
   // parcel sends a new version of `faqs.js` to the browser in development.
   module.hot.accept(() => {
      // Actually run the new version of your init function.
      init()
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and the bug report, would you mind sharing a link to the bug report with me?
I appreciate your snippet suggestion, however, async loading of the module through a promise still doesn't deliver changes of the updated faqs.js file. The same outcome arises as above. It works sync, just not through a promise.

Comment: Ignore my previous statement, of course your snippet does indeed resolve this, I misunderstood what you meant for a moment. It's not an ideal solution but does certainly work for now! Thanks

Comment: Glad it works! I haven't gotten around to filing the bug yet - I want to chew a bit on the desired behavior, taking into account your scenario (and others) before opening it. Here's a repo with a simple project that illustrates the solution: https://github.com/astegmaier/stackoverflow-parcel-hmr-dynamic-imports